# Secure your web api actions from authenticated users

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have this scenario:

1 User - N Project

1 Project - N Task

1 Project - N Comment

When a user is authenticated he can do:

```
/api/tasks/1
```

to delete his task but when he is doing /api/tasks/2 he deletes the task of someone else

```
/api/comments/1
```

to get his comment but when he is doing /api/comments/2 he reads the task of someone else

How can I intercept the user action (manipulating the URI) and check in a general way wether the user is allowed to delete this Task.

The Task and Comment does not know anything about a userId so how can forbide the user to delete other peoples data?

I am not talking about user and roles scenario. 
I am talking about manipulating the URI to delete ressources belonging to someone else.

UPDATE to answer @A Khudairy`s question

1) email + password is sent to api.

2) Api returns user with user token.

3) Then with every request the token is sent to api,( so that Iknow which user is doing what and handle this in backend.)

Comment: How are you implementing the authorization in your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I wouldn't personally solve this using the URI (I don't think there is a secure way to achieve that). I will implement a custom authorization filter Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426766/Custom-Filters-in-MVC-Authorization-Action-Result) for help on how to do that if you are not familiar with it.

In the filter I would use the token to get the user id, and use the route data to see what procedure is the user trying to do (and id of task or comment), then make decision if the user can continue based on that.

Filters can be registered then on top of controller class, or just on some action methods, or from global.asax to all actions  if required.

Comment: Within the custom AuthorizationFilter do I have access to the injected services in the ctor of the api controller?

Comment: I have just thought wether this makes really sense to use a filter for that task. I can not use one filter to rule them all... I would have to create multiple filters. I just think I could this make part of my business services and throw there a customException catched in the api controller returning a 403 then, what you think?

Comment: That make sense too. Whatever is good for you... we had a kind of a similar issue once and we used filters .. but both are okay I guess .. the advantage for filters that you would be returning the correct message "not authorized"

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173880/get-the-api-controllers-constructor-value-within-an-authorizefilter you can mark it as solution :P

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are either going to have to add the UserId to the Comment and Task entities so that you can check easily or you are going to need to ensure that the Task or Comment belongs to a project that the user has access too?

Unless I am misunderstanding your question?

If the Task or Comment does not have a UserId, how are you going to distinguish between your own comments and tasks and someone elses?